# How to set information in AppShell.xaml from other view in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I have this XML in Appshell.xaml file:

```
 <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Teal"
              RowDefinitions="Auto, *, *"
              Padding="10"
              HeightRequest="150">
            <toolkit:AvatarView x:Name="userAvatar"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                ImageSource="Images/profile.svg"
                                HeightRequest="80"
                                WidthRequest="80"
                                CornerRadius="70"
                                Opacity="0.6"
                                BorderWidth="0"
                                BorderColor="SaddleBrown" />
            <Label x:Name="userFullName"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Text=""
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   TextTransform="Uppercase"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label x:Name="userEmail"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Text=""
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

That code only shows an avatar, the user full name and the e-mail of a logged in user.

On the other hand, I have a LoginPage.xaml view which allows user to input his username and password.

Code behind of LoginPage does the actual login and when successful, I set the properties of a singleton object this way:

```
    private async Task<bool> IsCredentialCorrect(string username, string password)
    {
        var result = await api.PostDataAsync<AuthenticatedUser>($"/api/TimeAttendance/Trabajador/RemoteLogin", new { usuario = username, clave = password });
        _authenticatedUser.firstName = result?.firstName ?? string.Empty;
        _authenticatedUser.lastName = result?.lastName ?? string.Empty;
        _authenticatedUser.email = result?.email ?? string.Empty;
        _authenticatedUser.avatar = result?.avatar ?? string.Empty;

        return result != null;
    }
```

Finally, I overrode the `OnAppearing` method in AppShell.xaml.cs in order to set the user information from the singleton object, but when MainPage is shown and then I press the 3 horizontal lines to show the flyout side bar, `OnAppearing` is not called so the user information appears empty.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: One way to pass information between different places in code is [Community Toolkit / Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).